# Faster android input tap command

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to run fast input tap commands one after another, but they run with 1 second between them.
I'm wondering if there is an option to run them faster.

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer, but using monkeyrunner resolved this problem for me.

Comment: I have a similar problem but for me it takes between 2 and 3 seconds per command. Event when I execute the input commands directly on the device

Answer (score 5):

`input` is a java application and the "delay" you're seeing depends on how long it takes for your device to start a new java app. 1s is typical for older devices.

You can not do much about it if you want to keep using `input`. The alternatives to that would be either [using `sendevent` command](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html) or modifying `input` to accept series of coordinates for sending the whole gesture at once.

Answer (score 0):

While `sendevent` is certainly an alternative, it's cumbersome and device dependent.

Another alternative exists: *[CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/)*
*CulebraTester* provides a real-time point and click test recording through a web browser. This browser is connected to the Android device under test. 
The generated script is compatible with [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient), which you may know already.
The main deviation between both solutions is the use of a different back-end. *AndroidViewClient/culebra* normally uses `adb` as its back-end in most of the cases while *CulebraTester* uses a server running on the device backed by [Ui Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator.html).

This test script. which was automatically generated by *CulebraTester*

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2018  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2018-02-06 by CulebraTester 
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os
import time

import unittest
try:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require('androidviewclient>=12.4.0')
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, CulebraTestCase
from com.dtmilano.android.uiautomator.uiautomatorhelper import UiAutomatorHelper, UiScrollable, UiObject, UiObject2

TAG = 'CULEBRA'

class CulebraTests(CulebraTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': True, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
        cls.kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': True, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
        cls.options = {'start-activity': None, 'concertina': False, 'device-art': None, 'use-jar': False, 'multi-device': False, 'unit-test-class': True, 'save-screenshot': None, 'use-dictionary': False, 'glare': False, 'dictionary-keys-from': 'id', 'scale': 1, 'find-views-with-content-description': True, 'window': -1, 'orientation-locked': None, 'save-view-screenshots': None, 'find-views-by-id': True, 'log-actions': False, 'use-regexps': False, 'null-back-end': False, 'auto-regexps': None, 'do-not-verify-screen-dump': True, 'verbose-comments': False, 'gui': False, 'find-views-with-text': True, 'prepend-to-sys-path': False, 'install-apk': None, 'drop-shadow': False, 'output': None, 'unit-test-method': None, 'interactive': False}
        cls.sleep = 5

    def setUp(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).tearDown()

    def preconditions(self):
        if not super(CulebraTests, self).preconditions():
            return False
        return True

    def testSomething(self):
        if not self.preconditions():
            self.fail('Preconditions failed')

        _s = CulebraTests.sleep
        _v = CulebraTests.verbose

        t = time.time()
        for _ in range(100):
            self.vc.click(x=321, y=996)
        print (time.time() - t)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CulebraTests.main()
```

Only the timed loop sending 100 click events was added.
Running it shows how delay can be improved using this method.

Comment: thx. but i get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 30, in <module>
    pkg_resources.require('androidviewclient>=12.4.0')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 972, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 858, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'androidviewclient>=12.4.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Comment: How did you install? Easy_install, pip?

Comment: what librays should i install with pip?

Comment: so, what's the output of your `pip install androidviewclient` command? Perhaps, you should ask another question regarding that.

Comment: i have now installed androidviewclient. Now i get this error:      
Connecting to a device with serialno=.* with a timeout of 60 secs...
Connected to device with serialno=.*
Actual device serialno=9885e63848584a4537
E
======================================================================
ERROR: testSomething (__main__.CulebraTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 46, in setUp
    super(CulebraTests, self).setUp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 4543, in setUp
    self.vc = ViewClient(self.device, self.serialno, **self.kwargs2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 2556, in __init__
    self.uiAutomatorHelper = UiAutomatorHelper(device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/com/dtmilano/android/uiautomator/uiautomatorhelper.py", line 110, in __init__

Comment: raise RuntimeError('The target device does not contain the instrumentation for %s' % self.PACKAGE)
RuntimeError: The target device does not contain the instrumentation for com.dtmilano.android.culebratester

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.190s

FAILED (errors=1)

Comment: In the above script, try setting `'useuiautomatorhelper': False`. The reason why you are receiving the error is because you don't have [CulebraTester](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dtmilano.android.culebratester) and [instrumentation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dtmilano.android.culebratester.test) installed on the device. Once done you can set back `'useuiautomatorhelper': True`

Comment: ok thx it works. but it is slow, too. Around 1 touch per second

Comment: It depends on many factors, I run the test on a Pixel phone and the 100 touches take ~30 secs, so ~3 touches/sec. What's your device and rate?

Comment: Galaxy s7. Is it possible to make it faster? Maybe with monkeyrunner? Or will it be the same speed?

Comment: It's possible. You can generate Java instead of Python in **CulebraTester** and should run faster.

Comment: Tried in java and 100 events took ~11 secs, so yes, it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Like @ThomasW mentioned, the [monkeyrunner](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner) tool is able to automate taps very quickly (faster than my app will recognize them). Once you start it up (taking a couple seconds), the touch function is basically instant:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
for i in range(1, 10000):
    device.touch(x, y, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```