# android perform click with shell very slow

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb

hi i want to tap on the screen on my phone in a while loop. It does work but it is very slow. Around 1 time per second. How can I increase the speed?

```
while true
do
adb shell input tap 500 500
done
```

Comment: I added an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443112/faster-android-input-tap-command that may help you

Comment: does not work for me :(